# How to display data of inner loop according to value of outer loop

Tags: android

I am using nested listview in my application as xml files below.I am getting data from Json string as :

```
{
            "Result": [{
            "First Data": [
            {  "Name": "Ajay" },
            {  "Address": "xyz" },
            {  "Age": "12" },
            { "Mobile": "5489927" }
            ]
        }, {
            "Second Data":[
            { "City":"abc" },
            {  "State":"fdf" },
            { "Town":"abc" },
            {  "Street": "xyz" }
            ]
        },
            {
                "Third Data": [
                {  "Collage": "Yes" },
                { "School": "Yes" },
                { "University": "Yes" }
                ]
            }]
        }
```

I want to display fields "First Data,Second Data,Third Data" into textview of firstlist.xml and related data into inner listview.

firstlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sublist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

secondlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The JSON content you're receiving is not valid: objects must have key-value association. `{  "Name", "Ajay" }` must be `{ "name": "Ajay" }`.

Comment: your JSON response wrong. it must be somthing like this inside jsonarray ..                      
"contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com"             
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com"
               
        }

Comment: What is wrong in this JSON response ?

Comment: But my requirement is not like this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the JSON it should be {"key":"value"} not {"key","value"}
Tip : Instead of nested list you can use [exapndable list view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).